# Stop a Google Chrome Extensions with a On and Off Button. How?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have by default an External JS called alerton that will run on anywebppage when the extension is enabled.
I've also set up a Popup/Menu for when you click the Chrome Extension Icon at the top right. 
I want to when the user presses the button "off" to Turn off/Remove an external javascript file called "alerton"

After many many hours, I'm at a loss as to what I need to do to get this to work!
I've looked at chrome.contentSettings.javascript  However it doesn't seem like I can disable just one particular Javascript file.

I'm hoping someone has an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is by reading and modifying a boolean variable in a [Background Page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) and use [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to communicate to and from your content-script and popup page. You can define a Background Page in your Manifest as such:

```
  ....
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  ....
```

The background.js would look something like this:

```
var isExtensionOn = true;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "setOnOffState") {
        isExtensionOn = request.data.value;
    }

    if (request.cmd == "getOnOffState") {
        sendResponse(isExtensionOn);
    }
});
```

From your PopUp.html and your content-script you could then call the background.js to read and set the `isExtensionOn` variable.

```
//SET VARIABLE
var isExtensionOn = false;
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "setOnOffState", data: { value: isExtensionOn } });

//GET VARIABLE
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "isAutoFeedMode" }, function (response) {
    if (response == true) {
     //Run the rest of your content-script in here..
    }
});
```

Comment: Since Inline scripts are not allowed. How would you create your PopuP.html page?
You would need a Popup.js as well. So I know you would need to include <script src="popup.js></script> However, what else would you put in the Popup HTML then?

Comment: Yes you'd also need a popup.js which would get and set the on/off state (using the methods above). Typically you would have some UI on your popup.html to allow the on/off state to be modified, the simplest method would be a checkbox.